# What's the easiest way to make obsidian?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft what is the easiest way to make obsidian without using the creative game mode? Do i use water buckets? Or tunnel my way to water?

Comment: If water meets a lava flow, it will create a cobblestone block. Obsidian will only form if water meets a lava "source" block, though if you find a lava pool it will be all or mostly source blocks.

Comment: As a side note, for completeness, there are tutorials online for obsidian generators which work by turning redstone into obsidian, and through other glitches. Scouring the Youtubes might turn up something that works, though the setup may be more complicated than it's worth.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bring a bucket of water with you when you go mining. If you come across a lava lake, pour it on the block next to the lava. This will make a "blob" of obsidian.

Then what you want to do is pick up the water again, then mine one obsidian block to make a little hole.

Pour the water bucket into that hole (even if the ground is stone, this is to make sure it's safe) then mine obsidian in a line. If there is lava under you the water will flow and change it to obsidian before you burn or the drop burns.

Continue this method as needed until you have enough obsidian.

also, make sure you have a diamond pick in order to harvest it... Enchantments aren't required, but they help.

Comment: Also, if it's not a tiny little pool of lava, I'd recommend using the bucket to move the lava away from its pool before cooling it. This prevents lava flows burning the dropped obsidian blocks, and stops lava flow getting out of control in general.

Comment: that is what the bucket of water is for, once you finish mining, there will be a "pit" of obsidian, walls and everything to "protect" messy lava flowing

Comment: Ah, I had misread and hadn't realised you leave the water down as you dig. A good method :)

Comment: OMG this is a gosu strategy! I've always been digging a separate "obsidian processor", scoop lava by one, pour into a 1-meter pool, pour-scoop water, mine it, repeat. This is COOL.

Answer (score 3):

You can only mine obsidian with a diamond pick. Efficiency enchantments will make the process much less tedious.

Alternatively if water touches a lava *source block* it will turn it into obsidian. The easiest way to do this is find a lava lake and just place a bucket of water on top of it.

If you want to construct a nether portal, then you'll have to carefully place buckets of lava, one at a time, in the correct places, and then 'freeze' them with water.

Comment: Your answer very briefly mentions where obsidian comes from, but doesn't go into much useful detail about safely and effectively farming obsidian - I feel a slightly more thorough explanation of the things you mention would be useful. I like the note about creating a nether portal without a diamond pick, though.

Answer (score 0):

I farm it very similar to what was stated by JLaBella (then again I only play on the 360 version), but mine tries to take away all risk, in case there is more lava underneath the current obsidian.

Here are the steps I take:

1. Take a bucket of water, diamond pickaxe, and find a lava pool.
2. Pour out the water to make the initial obsidian where the lava used to be.
3. Pick up the water, then put down a piece of coblestone or any other block in the middle of the obsidian.
4. Put the water on top of that block you just laid.
5. Mine away. As long as you stay close to where you put the water on that block, it should always stop the lava even if there is more lava under the obsidian you mine. (I try to give myself a block or two away from where there could be potential lava).

Also I use this method so my obsidian doesn't get swallowed up by lava.